# Real Time message broadcasting using SignalR and Azure SQL Db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, signalr-hub

We are having real time application which is hosted on on-premises(IIS) using .Net core 2.1. Whenever there is an update happening in a table, we have to capture the change and show in page and to achieve this we have implemented SignalR. Since we are using Azure SQL db, we couldn't SQLTableDependency as it doesn't have Service Broker.

**Current Implementation:**

We have created a Stored procedure to check the records which captures changes and where timeout for stored procedure  is set to 90 sec. Once the execution completes it captures the change and push it to front-end. In order to achieve this, we have kept a loop running for 10 min in back-end.

**Problem Statement:**
As number of users increases, the overall SQL CPU consumption is high. Is there a way to reduce the CPU cost or any other approach to get real time data using Azure SQL db and SignalR?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR Service is **a fully managed Azure service** that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications over HTTP.

It seems there is less compatibility between Azure SQL and SignalR. From [this discussion](https://forums.asp.net/t/2105348.aspx?SignalR%20on%20Azure%20Sql%20database) also we can see that there is a compatibility issue between these two.

The solution to this problem is to use SQL server instead of Azure SQL DB. You can install SQL Server on one of the servers or another option is to install SQL Server in one VM on Azure.

You can follow this two documents for the process:

1. [SignalR Scaleout with SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server).
2. [SignalR with SQL Server](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-Update-Notifications-in-ASP-NET-M).